# how to change the length of the ComboBox in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, combobox

I have a ComboBox have four lines each option, when I select an option, it will only display one line, so I'm wondering if I can make my comboBox larger.

my combo box new looks like this

```
 |some text here |
```

I want my combo box looks like

```
 |some text here|
 |some text here|
 |some text here|
```

I have tried custom renderer implement ListCellRenderer, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer{

    public ComboBoxRenderer(){
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel(){
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(200, 100);
            }
        };
        label.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        return label;
    }
}

allBuyer = new JComboBox<Buyer>();
ComboBoxRenderer renderer= new ComboBoxRenderer();
renderer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,130));
allBuyer.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Is there any other ways to change the length of combobox?
Can someone help me?

EDIT:
It's actually really weird! I was using Eclipse on MAC and all i got it that one line, while I tried using NetBeans on Windows, same program, it worked!!

is there a reason for it? Or MAC just won't fit into anything?

Comment: What you need is JList.

Comment: Forget the render, post your code where you populate the combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have four lines each option,

Try adding the text as HTML to the combo box. Then you can control the line breaks for the text. Something like:

```
comboBox.addItem("<html>line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>line4</html>");
```

Comment: I already have four lines on each option, The problem is cause by MAC system, but thank you anyway